# How to save data in Asp .net core through method called in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have method which is called in **Startup.cs** in that method there is an event, after event triggers it must save data to my database like code below

```
public  void SaveRecievedSmsToDb(string phoneNumber, string messageBody, 
    DateTime messageDateTime, string state)
{
    ContactService contactService = new ContactService(_context, _httpContextAccessor);
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService(_context, _httpContextAccessor);

    var contact = contactService.GetContactByNr(phoneNumber);
    var currentUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var newMessage = new Message();
    {
        newMessage.UserId = currentUserId;
        newMessage.ContactId = contact.ContactId;
        newMessage.Body = messageBody;
        newMessage.Date = messageDateTime;
        newMessage.isDelivered = true;
        newMessage.State = state;
        messageService.AddMessage(newMessage);
    }
```

Problem is that this way requires Services which uses **DbContext** and **HttpContextAccessor** and in the end i need to write them into **Startup.cs** as injection what isn't working and throwing `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SmsSender.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'SmsSender.Startup'.` 
What will be the best way to save that data from event?

```
    public class Startup
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AtSmsReceiver _atSmsReceiver = new AtSmsReceiver();//If I'm trying to use Http and AppDb contexts it asking to pass them here

        //Opens port for runtime
        COMPortSettings.OpenPort();
        //Runtime sms receiver
        _atSmsReceiver.ReceiveSms();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(_configuration.GetConnectionString("SmsSender")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddScoped<IContactService, ContactService>();
        services.AddScoped<IMessageService, MessageService>();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddTransient<IMacroService, MacroService>();
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
 //All other logic...
}
```

Comment: Where did you call this method? Could you show your startup.cs?

Comment: @Win I'm calling it in **ConfigureServices** to be more correctly this method is nested in another one which is called to work on runtime. Edited in my Startup.cs